# simple ThreadPool implementations

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, asynchronous

I would like to ask you for a code review of my c++11 Thread Pool implementation. Your constructive criticism is welcome! Could you give me some ideas how to extend it?

The main idea is to synchronise access to tasks with condition variable.

### ThreadPoolExecutor.cpp

```
#include "ThreadPoolExecutor.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

namespace ThreadPool
{
    ThreadPoolExecutor::ThreadPoolExecutor(int maxWorkers)
    {
        this->maxWorkers = maxWorkers;
    }

    ThreadPoolExecutor::~ThreadPoolExecutor()
    {
        this->poolManager.join();
    }

    void ThreadPoolExecutor::ScheduleTask(std::function<void()> task)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(taskQueueMutex);
        bool wasEmpty = this->taskQueue.empty();
        this->taskQueue.push(task);
        if (wasEmpty)
        {
            this->notEmptyTaskQueue.notify_one();
        }

        lock.unlock();
    }

    void ThreadPoolExecutor::Run()
    {
        this->poolManager = std::thread(&ThreadPoolExecutor::ManagePool, this);
    }

    void ThreadPoolExecutor::ManagePool()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->maxWorkers; i++)
        {
            this->workers.push_back(std::thread(&ThreadPoolExecutor::Worker, this));
        }

        for (auto &thread : this->workers)
        {
            thread.join();
        }
    }

    void ThreadPoolExecutor::Worker()
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        std::cout << "Hello from thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
#endif
        while (1)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(taskQueueMutex);
            if (this->taskQueue.empty())
            {
                this->notEmptyTaskQueue.wait(lock);
            }

            auto task = this->taskQueue.front();
            this->taskQueue.pop();
            lock.unlock();
            task();
        }
    }
}
```

### ThreadPoolExecutor.h

```
#ifndef THREADPOOLEXECUTOR_H_
#define THREADPOOLEXECUTOR_H_

#include <functional>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include "Task.h"
#include <condition_variable>

namespace ThreadPool
{
    class ThreadPoolExecutor
    {
    public:
        ThreadPoolExecutor(int maxWorkers);
        ~ThreadPoolExecutor();
        void ScheduleTask(std::function<void()> task);
        void Run();

    private:
        int maxWorkers;
        std::vector<std::thread> workers;
        std::thread poolManager;
        std::queue<std::function<void()>> taskQueue;
        std::condition_variable notEmptyTaskQueue;
        void ManagePool();
        std::mutex taskQueueMutex;
        void Worker();
    };
}
#endif
```

And finally usage.

### Program.cs

```
#include "ThreadPoolExecutor.h"
#include "ExampleTask.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace ThreadPool;

int main()
{
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(4);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int random = std::rand() % 6;
        std::chrono::seconds timeout(random);
        executor.ScheduleTask([i, timeout](){
            std::cout << "no " << i << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(timeout);
        });
    }

    executor.Run();

    ExampleTask task;
    executor.ScheduleTask(task);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(15));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int random = std::rand() % 6;
        std::chrono::seconds timeout(random);
        executor.ScheduleTask([i, timeout](){
            std::cout << "no " << i << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(timeout);
        });
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## ThreadManager.h

What is Task.h? Why are you including it? I see no names that aren't covered by the standard headers you include.

There's no apparent order to your private members. You mix methods and data members; it looks like the members are added in the order they were written, as opposed to some logical order. I recommend putting your methods before your data members (my recommendation matches the [Google C++ Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Declaration_Order)), and determining a logical order within each set.

In general, the header is the place to document your interface. What are the semantics of `ScheduleTask`? Can it be called from multiple threads without mutual exclusion? Will `Run` return? Does `ThreadPoolExecutor` reuse threads after there work is complete? If so, will `ThreadPoolExecutor` ever destroy threads after creating them? Does the destructor block?

`Worker` is an odd name for a method. It is the usual practice that function names should be some sort of verb phrase; `Worker` is a noun, and it doesn't give a lot of insight into what it does.

`maxWorkers` should probably be declared `const`; it shouldn't change after construction.

Comments on the private data members should clearly indicate which members are guarded by the mutex.

## ThreadManager.cpp

Constructors should use initializers wherever possible:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor::ThreadPoolExecutor(int maxWorkers) : maxWorkers(maxWorkers) {}
```

This will allow the member to be declared `const`.

Your destructor throws if `Run` has never been called: A default constructed `thread` is not joinable. That's not the biggest problem: Your destructor never returns if `maxWorkers > 0` because none of your calls to `join` ever complete.

It is distracting (and unidiomatic!) to see unnecessary `this->` warts prepended to each member access. If you must have a visual indicator that you are accessing members rather than local variables, adopt a naming convention for your data members (common ones I've seen: maxWorkers_, m_maxWorkers).

In `ScheduleTask`, it is unnecessary to call `lock.unlock();`. `std::unique_lock` unlocks its owned mutex in its destructor; when I see explicit unlocking, I expect that it's because of complicated locking semantics (e.g. conditional unlocking, or unlocking before `lock` goes out of scope, as in `Worker`) and look around for the complication; there's no such complication here.

`maxWorkers` appears to be a misnomer as you never have fewer workers. Maybe `numWorkers`?

Comment: I agree with your recomendations. But I don't think quoting google c++ style guide is good. The google C++ style guide is designed for google (and to support there legacy C++ systems). It is not considered a generically good C++ style guide.

Comment: @LokiAstari The Google C++ style guide has its plusses and minuses, but I don't think it's clearly bad; certainly its advice on how to organize code is fine, even if it is a bit old-fashioned when it comes to exceptions and functional style.

Comment: I disagree. There are so many bad things in there (I did notice that it has been updated). But just a quick glance [Doing Work in Constructors](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Doing_Work_in_Constructors#Doing_Work_in_Constructors). Advice: don't do it because if things go wrong you have no object to check error codes from. So basically that is suggesting two phase initialization. I am sure I could find lots more. I consider this a travesty of style guide for modern C++. It is absolutely fine for internal google projects because they have a specific goal.

Comment: Yep, there is unnecessary "Task.h" include in ThreadPoolExecutor.h. Thank you for google c++ style, I'll familiarize with it. I agree, that the order is the order of writing code.

Comment: What do you mean by "In general, the header is the place to document your interface"? Should I place documentation there? And I agree that Worker is odd name, maybe  "RunWorker" is better?

Comment: **ThreadPoolExecutor.cpp** You are right, my main thread is not joinable when I do not call Run. I could initialize it in constructor. But I can't figure out how to fix "maxWorkers>0"situation. Do you have any suggestions how to fix that? But I disagree with "this->", isn't it that just a styling convention? I am not cpp developer, but for me it is just question of taste? m_maxWorkers looks like hungarian notation for me. And many many thanks for your code review! That's great to have a feedback for my work!

Comment: @LokiAstari 2-phase initialization is bad, and they should remove the `Init` recommendation from that section, but using factory functions is certainly a reasonable solution. It is generally bad style to have an operation that could fail (and thereby leave the object partially constructed) in constructors. However, I take your point. Do you have an alternative style guide to suggest?

Comment: @klouch Yes, you should document the class as a whole and each of the public functions so that users can use it correctly. I mentioned in the answer some of the questions that documentation should answer.

Comment: @klouch This answer on StackOverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1229360/66509) addresses your Hungarian notation concerns.

Comment: @klouch `maxWorkers>0` problem can be addressed in a number of ways. One way would be to have a state variable (boolean or preferably an enum) as a class member. Your `Worker` function, on waking up, could check whether the state is `SHUTDOWN`, and stop checking the queue in that case. In your destructor, you could set the state and call `notify_all` on your condition variable before joining with the manager thread.